# Bond in relation to US T-Bill/Risk-Free rate

Tags: fixed-income

By looking at the following [charts](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14259/correlation-between-sp500-returns-and-10y-us-treasuries-yields) , i wondered about how to plot a fixed income security against a risk free bond.

I have the bond price time series but I am not sure what US T-Bill rate I should use as a benchmark for my plot.

My horizon would be 2-3 days so I don't want to hold the bond forever.

Answer (score 1):

There does not exist a rule to choose properly the risk-free rate, but, usually, one chooses the 1-month T-Bill or the 3-month T-Bill in the academic literature; often, it used the overnight interest rate too.

I suggest you to choose the 1st one, because, according to me, it  mirrors better the concept of risk-free, since it is more liquid and with less perceived risk than the 3-mont one. Moreover, a fixed- income security is perceived as riskier as longer is the maturity, so, reasonably, you should use the 1-Month T-Bill rate as risk free rate.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I get the bid/ask for the TBill? BTW, my bond is trading at 101.25 (premium) are TBills quoted the same way? If not how can I normalize it so it will appear to be in the same notation

Comment: Sorry @user3589054, but this is not a forum but a Q&A site, so, you should ask this question for by posting another one and not here! Anyway, if the answer fulfilled the question, please mark the answer as checked! If I am able to do that, I will be happy to answer to second question after.

Comment: The overnight rate is also used in some cases.

Comment: Yes, I'll update the answer! Thanks for the suggestion @pyCthon!